# Could Refrigerators Take In Cold Outside Air To Save Energy?

Tags: carnot-cycle

We heat up rooms, then we use that warm air and cool it down in refrigerators. Each is a lossy, energy requiring process. This seems thermodynamically inefficient. Couldn't refrigerators get cold air from the outside, reducing the amount they have to cool?

Comment: Some expensive Refrigerators are designed with most efficient thermal insulators so they actually don't allow heat to flow inside and outside the Refrigerators except the radiating mesh.

Comment: Refrigerators reject heat into your house as they operate.  If the air is cold enough outside to keep food cold (i.e., 35 deg F), it makes some sense to avoid pulling in outside air, as the heat that would normally get rejected into the house from the refrigerator has to be made up by some other source of heat.

Comment: But not all sources of heat come at equal cost. We can assume that a refrigerator is less efficient than the purpose-built technology we use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A refrigerator's common-language 'efficiency' is in physics its Coefficient of Performance, given by

$COP \le \dfrac{T_C}{T_H - T_C}$

Where $T_H$ and $T_C$ are the temperatures of the cold region (where the refrigerator coils are) and hot region (where the radiator coils are) respectively. Try graphing $y=1/(x-1)$ if you want a visual picture of what happens when you vary the temperature of the hot region (e.g. by building your refrigerator halfway through a wall so that it could use a chilly outdoor temperature for its hot region).

COP is the amount of cooling work done (heat moved from the cold reservoir to the hot reservoir) per unit input work (for electricity, per watt-hour). Bigger COP is better. Infinite COP means the cold region and the hot region are the same temperature (an open window is a heat pump with an infinite cooling COP: you don't need to plug it in to make it keep the inside temperature and outside temperature the same). Negative cooling COP would mean that the "hot" region is actually colder than the "cold" region, so (assuming your machine was set up correctly) you could run it in reverse as a heat engine and extract power from it, but at that point we'd want to just model it as a heat engine and use Carnot's Theorem.

However: as far as the rest of the house is concerned, your refrigerator is just an ordinary electric heater. If you're heating your house anyway, you're probably better off rejecting heat from the refrigerator inside the house rather than wasting the rejected heat on the outside world. On the other hand, if you're air-conditioning your house despite the cooler outside temperature (maybe it's humid outside or full of pollution or loud noises and you want to run the AC instead of just opening a window), the more heat you reject to the outdoors instead of to the indoors, the better, on top of increased COP for your refrigerator.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the earlier answer by contributor 'g s': when the outside temperature is colder than the inside temperature then it doesn't actually matter how conversion of electric energy to heat is distributed among the various household appliances. Assuming that the heater of a particular room is regulated by a thermostat: if the heat exchanger (at the back of the refrigerator) is contributing x units of heat to the overall heating of the room then the contribution that the heater in that room needs to provide will be correspondingly less.

What you are asking about, of course, is the case where AC is running in order to make the inside temperature lower than the unbearably hot outside temperature.

I concur: under those circumstances the heating of the room by the refrigerator is bonkers.

Unfortunately: in most cases avoiding that inefficiency will be complicated, and complicated in a way that makes it costly.

An AC unit has two heat exchangers, one located inside the house, one outside the house, connected by air ducts.

A customized refrigerator would be like that. It would be designed to be installed similar to the way an AC unit is used.

In a pre-fabricated house there would be the option of integrating the AC system and the refrigerator system. Then the refrigerator is an item that comes with the house, instead of being an appliance that you bring in.

Would there be a market for that?  I don't know. It may be that most people will feel that they want the model of refrigerator they use to be a personal choice.

Incidentally, the Tesla model Y introduced an integrated thermal management system. The hub of that system is an component named: [Octovalve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9U2hIoO-GU)

Answer (score 1):

They could indeed. In fact, in cabins built during the California gold rush, the miners would cut openings in the kitchen wall behind the pantry in which they kept their perishables so freezing cold winter air could circulate into the pantry while not getting directly into the kitchen.

Those openings were made small enough so that animals could not get into the pantry and eat the food inside.

This was very effective in the winter, but obviously not during the summer.

Comment: Yeah. Europe is pretty far up north. They shouldn't need refrigerators for half the year. Yet nobody does the 'holes in the house' thing.

Comment: @JohnBig Try putting your food in the freezer every night an hour after sundown and moving it to the refrigerator at dawn, and see what happens to it after a day or two.